# Custom variant text color in buttons

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'd like to change the theme of my bootstrap-vue project. I changed the primary and secondary color. Now the background of my buttons is customized, but I wondered about the text color. It just stays white. I can change it with

```
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle
{color:$myColorl;}
```

but I thought there should be a more simple and elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just tested this on codepen and it works for me :)

```
$myColorl: #000 !important;

.btn-primary{
   color:$myColorl;
}
```